# Is $\{a,c,e,g\}$ an equivalence class?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$ is is partitioned into these three partitions:

$\{a, c, e, g\}$

$\{b, d\}$

$\{f\}$

and an equivalence relation is produced by these partitions, is $\{a,c,e,g\}$ an equivalence class?

Comment: That's not a partition: b is in two sets, and c is in none.

Comment: The relation you have defined ("$a~b$ iff $a$ and $b$ are both in the same set) not transitive: $a~b$ and $b~d$ but $a$ is not related to $d$.

Comment: Crap.  I meant for the first one to say {a, c, e, g} instead of {a, b, e, g}.  Fixed it now; thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As updated, yes.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) has more

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed to know.  Thanks.